# Is it OK to use two different versions of okhttp library in my app?

Tags: android, okhttp

In my app, I am using the [latest version of the **okhttp** library](https://square.github.io/okhttp/#download), by adding this to my app's dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
```

However, I am now adding another third party library (called **Mintegrate**) to my app which requires v2.7.5 of **okhttp**:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
```

Is it OK to have both these dependencies together in my app's build.gradle?

PS - I have tried omitting v2.7.5, but when I do that, the app crashes with this error:

> ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient

Comment: Yes, it's ok. It shouldn't be a problem since the packages differ.

Comment: You can use new version of OKHTTP.

Comment: I'm also including two versions in our app for the exact same reason (3rd party library) and it's working without any issue. As @Héctor says, packages differ. See Jake's Wharton statement on that http://jakewharton.com/java-interoperability-policy-for-major-version-updates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm also including two versions in our app for the exact same reason (3rd party library) and it's working without any issue. As @Héctor says in his comment, packages differ. See [Jake's Wharton statement on that](http://jakewharton.com/java-interoperability-policy-for-major-version-updates/).

Comment: BTW, you should tell that third party library to fix their library to use OkHttp 3. The HTTPS policy of OkHttp 2 is out of date.

Answer (score 1):

You could force the dependency with the [`resolutionStrategy`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/ResolutionStrategy.html#force-java.lang.Object...-) in your `build.gradle` e.g.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
}

dependencies {
 .....
}
```

Comment: How this would help? `com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient` <> `okhttp3.OkHttpClient`  ...